# Reading a Firebird Command (SQLDA error) - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebird, sqldatareader

I'm using ASP.NET and C# to make a GridView with information from a table in a Firebird database. But when I tried to read my FbCommand, I got this error:

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: 'SQLDA error'
>   ErrorCode 335544583

I'm using Firebird 3.0 (already tried with 2.5 too, as well as modify firebird.config).

```
 List<String> columnData = new List<String>();

        using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection("my_connection_string_is_here"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string query = " select PRONT, NOME, NASC from ricadpac ";
            query += " where NOME is not null and NASC is not null ";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNome.Text))
                query += String.Format(" and NOME like '{0}' ", txtNome.Text);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDataNasc.Text) && VerificarData(txtDataNasc.Text))
                query += String.Format(" and NASC = '{0}' ", txtDataNasc.Text);

            query += " order by PRONT ";

            using (FbCommand command = new FbCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        columnData.Add(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                        columnData.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                        columnData.Add(reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString());
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

The connection and command are apparently ok, but the ExecuteReader() doesn't working for nothing. Exactly in this line:

```
 using (FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ADO.net provider are you using? What are the datatypes on `PRONT`, `NOME` and `NASC` in table `ricadpac`. Also check if the exception contains more information, because afaik an SQLDA error usually also has a more specific error description.

Comment: Also  note that your use of `String.Format` to add values into a query string is unsafe and can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/csharp  // also u may try with http://ibprovider.com

Comment: @MarkRotteveel same err code at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-180 /// FB 2.1 DOCs: -804 335544583 dsql_sqlda_err SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/type of variables

Comment: My ADO version is 5.9.1.0. PRONT (INTEGER), NOME (VARCHAR(45)) and NASC (DATE).

Thanks for the advice about String.Format